# Issue when importing contact information in Mautic 3.0.0

Tags: csv, import, mautic

I am currently using Mautic 3.0.0 with PHP 7.3.20.

I tried importing a CSV file from my local computer to Mautic. I uploaded the file and I chose **,** as a delimiter, **"** as an enclosure, \ as an escape and 100 as a limit (the default import settings). I was then redirected to the next step without any issues and because the file’s header column matches Mautic’s custom fields’ aliases, I just clicked on “Import”. I was then redirected to Mautic’s import history page and the import’s status was “Queued”.

The problem is that even after several hours, the progress is still 0% (0 rows inserted, updated or ignored). I thought that the reason was the slow connection or the file’s volume, but trying to import a much smaller file gave the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you make sure that you add `mautic:import` command to the cron jobs? please check https://docs.mautic.org/en/contacts/import-contacts#background-import for the import command cron jobs configuration.

You can also read other mautic cron jobs configuration in here: https://docs.mautic.org/en/setup/cron-jobs

Comment: Hello @syamcode and thank you for your reply! The problem is -as you mentioned above- related to setting up the cron jobs. I added the following cron jobs: **mautic:segments:update**; **mautic:campaigns:update**; **mautic:campaigns:trigger** and **mautic:import**, then I reimported the csv file and this time it worked :-)